# TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbigousTime in Mono Framework

Tags: c#, mono

I am currently porting a C# application to Mono. To determine if a given time is ambigous and can refer to multiple UTC times, I am using the following method:

```
public static bool IsAmbiguousTime(DateTimeOffset date)
{
        TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        return tz.IsAmbiguousTime(date);
}
```

Unfortunately, this method return always false, even if I use ambiguous dates. After having a look at the Mono documentation, it looks like this is only partially supported.

Is there anyone aware of a solution that is working with Mono as well? If not, I have probably to write an own implementation.

More information about the IsAmbiguousTime method can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396403%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Maybe NodaTime can help you with that? http://nodatime.org/

Comment: NodaTime looks definitively helpful, I'll have a look at that in detail...